# Why is my PHP variable displayed as incomprehensible with a character sequence of % instead of its real value in Chinese?

Tags: php, character-encoding, urlencode

I'm trying to use this `embed` PHP Package (https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed/). However, I when I try to display the display of the `Title` with the variable `$info->title` of all the Pages having the Asian languages like that of the URL [https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/亞馬遜公司](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8), this returns me `%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8` as `title` instead of this as the real title `亞馬遜公司`.

Why the display of an incomprehensible character like: `%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8` instead of `亞馬遜公司`? ??

**So how do I get my `$info->title` variable to display as it should: `亞馬遜公司` ???**

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode the string. Maybe the library does not.

```
$title = '%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8';
var_dump(rawurldecode($title));
```

will print

`string(15) "亞馬遜公司"`

Answer (score 0):

You should include a header like this before any output in your file: `<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>`.

Additionally, if you are getting your data from a database, you will need to make sure it is encoded and retrieved from the database as UTF8.

If you are outputting HTML, you will want to include the following element nested in your `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. You may also want to declare the language using the `lang` attribute on the `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The zh.wikipedia URL you showed us is URL-encoded. To display it on a page you'll have to [URL-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it then [HTML-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) it before you echo it or otherwise send it to a browser.

```php
$displayableTitle = htmlentities( 
       urldecode( '%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8' ) );
```